# Excluding a sub directory from executing CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I have the following project structure

```
MainProj
 |-SubDir1
 |   |-Docs
 |       |-CMakeLists.txt
 |   |-Src
 |   |-CMakeLists.txt
 |-SubDir2
 |   |-Src
 |   |-CMakeLists.txt
 |-CMakeLists.txt
```

In my `Mainproj` `cmakeList.txt` I am using

```
Add_subdirectory(subDir1)
Add_subdirectory(subDir2)
```

So now I want to exclude the `mainproj/subdir1/doc` from the build process. But I couldn't find a direct way of doing the same in CMake scripts. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that `mainproj/subdir1/CMakeLists.txt` doesn't use `add_subdirectory(Docs)`, then `mainproj/subdir1/doc` won't be built. Probably, you need to show more code, which relates to the problem, don't you?

Comment: Normally I do this with an option like OPTION(BUILD_DOCS "Build the documentation" ON)  that is default on and a if( BUILD_DOCS) add_subdirectory(Docs) endif()

Comment: Ok,My bad ,the add_subdirectory(docs) is being called from Mainproj/Subdir1/CMakeList.txt. I want this to be executed like if complete build then dont add_subdirectory (docs) if module build of subDir1 then add it.This is my first cmake task ,so i have minimal knowledge on this. So i think i need to set a variable/macro on parent cmakelist.txt and i should check that condition.

Comment: add_subdirectory(doc EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL) will exclude it from being built by the default all target.